# Failed to fetch events (404) from Google+ Calendars after OAuth 2.0 for limited devices

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-oauth, pebble-watch

I'm writing a watchapp for Pebble to show events from the Google calendars.

I'm using Auth 2.0 to authenticate the user as described in [this](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ForDevices) document.

Then I retrieve events using [this](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) API v3 call, specifying my *access_token* in the authorization header.

For the calendars created and managed by the user **everything works fine**.

However if I try to get the events from the Google+ calendars, such as Birthdays (#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com) or Holidays in Italy (en.italian#holiday@group.v.calendar.google.com), the answer is 404:

```
   {
        "error": {
            "errors": [
                {
                    "domain": "global",
                    "reason": "notFound",
                    "message": "Not Found"
                }
            ],
            "code": 404,
            "message": "Not Found"
        }
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? Or is it a bug of the Calendar API?

Comment: It could be an escaping issue. You can check in the API explorer that retrieving events from these works just fine: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/calendar/v3/calendar.events.list?calendarId=%2523contacts%2540group.v.calendar.google.com&_h=1& (don't forget to authenticate in the top right corner)

Comment: Yeah sorry! I forgot to mention that from the API explorer I can successfully retrieve the events from these calendars. What do you mean with 'escaping issue'?

Comment: I've figured it out just now. Using encodeURIComponent on the calendarID it finally works! You saved my day luc, thank you very much!

Comment: Cool, thanks for letting me know. It would be great if you pasted your fixed code as the answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to luc, here's the answer!

I was calling the service this way:

```
var GET_EVENT_LIST = "https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/%s/events";

var calendarId = "#contacts@group.v.calendar.google.com";
var token_type = "Bearer";
var access_token = "...";

var url = sprintf(GET_EVENT_LIST, calendarId);

var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET", url, true);
req.setRequestHeader("Authorization", token_type + " " + access_token);
req.send(null);
```

I solved changing the fifth line to:

```
var url = sprintf(GET_EVENT_LIST, encodeURIComponent(calendarId));
```